# Why Azure VM is not receiving a HTTP GET response?

Tags: azure, http, curl, postman, azure-virtual-machine

I've encountered an interesting problem when trying to make a HTTP request from Azure VM. It appears that when the request is ran from this VM the response never arrives. I tried using a custom C# code that makes an HTTP request and Postman. In both cases we can see in the logs on the target API side that the response has been sent, but no data is received on the origin VM. The exact same C# request and Postman request work outside of this VM in multiple networks and machines. **The only tool that actually works for this request on VM side is Curl Bash terminal** but it is not an option based on current requirements.

Tried on multiple Azure VM sizes, on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019.

The target API is on-premise hosted and it requires around 5 minutes for the data to be sent back. Payload is very small but due to the computing performed on the API side it takes a while to generate. Modifying this API is not an option.

So to be clear- the requests are perpetually stuck until the timeout on client side is reached (if it was configured). Does anybody know what could be a reason for this?

Comment: I've observed behaviour along these lines when network routing has directed the return packets along a different route that then hits a firewall - you can have https on 443 authorised from the VM but then not see a response make it back because it traverses a network route different to the outbound. Afraid I'm far from an expert and can't suggest exactly what to look for, but network routing could be a line of inquiry.

Comment: @TomW Thanks for the suggestion, I tried enabling all ports for the tests but it did not help. Also what is interesting a different get operation on the same API works just fine, it's this particular one that causes issues (but it also by far the longest running one in standard scenarios). It also baffles me how curl bash can manage to get it 100% right every time.

Answer (score 0):

If these transfers take longer than 4 minutes without keep alives, Azure will typically close the connection.

You should be able to see this by monitoring the connection with wireshark.

[TCP Timeouts can be configured when using a Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout?tabs=tcp-reset-idle-portal), but you can also try adding keep alives in your API server if possible.